# What regex pattern to use to extract the number from an xml input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, regex, match

My input text is as blow:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2</string>
```

What regex pattern to use to extract the number from the above input?

```
var pattern = "<string ?>?</string>"; // how to write this?
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another aproach using LinqToXml:

```
var ele = XElement.Parse("<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">2</string>");
var valueString = ele.Value; //valueString = "2";
```

**Update**

And for regex: I would extend solution from @Oded with `(?<=startRegex)` and `(?=endRegex)` (lookbehind and lookahead), so the unnecessary `<string>` tag will be omitted in match value.

```
(?<=<string[^>]+>)([0-9]+)(?=</string>)
```

Comment: that's the best way! don't need to use REGEX!

Answer (score 5):

This pattern should do the trick:

```
"<string[^>]+>([0-9]+)</string>"
```

Breakdown:

```
<string   - Match the string <string
[^>]+     - Followed by one or more characters that are not >
>         - Followed by >
(         - Start capturing group
[0-9]+    - Followed by one or more of the digits 0-9
)         - End capturing group
</string> - Followed by the string </string>
```

If the example is the whole string, you may want to anchor it using `^` and `$` at the start and end respectively.

Note I am using `[0-9]` and not `\d`, as in .NET `\d` will match on any Unicode numeral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the non-regex way of doing it.

```
string str = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">2</string>";
int startIndex = str.IndexOf('>');
int endIndex = str.LastIndexOf('<');
int numberLenght =  (endIndex - startIndex) - 1;
string result = str.Substring(startIndex + 1, numberLenght);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to extract the number:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example for how to extract the number from an xml string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string ExtractNumber(string xml)
    {
        // Extracted number.
        string number = string.Empty;

        // Input text
        xml = @"<string xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"">2</string>";

        // The regular expression for the match.
        // You can use the parentesis to isolate the desired number into a group match. "(\d+?)"
        var pattern = @"<string.*?>(\d+?)</string>";

        // Match the desired part of the xml.
        var match = Regex.Match(xml, pattern);

        // Verify if the match has sucess.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, use the group value to isolate the number.
            number = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        return number;
    }
```

This is the way that I used to solve this problem.